# How android camera api2 achieved in supporting multi-surfaces outputs

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

Say that i set up 3 output surfaces.

1. SurfaceView with `480p`
2. MediaCodec's InputSurface with `1080p`
3. ImageReader with `YUV` format with `720p`

How did android managed to generate different resolution with requested data format?

How camera sensor driver involved in this?

Or the camera sensor can only output one certain resolution & format, then android camera framework did the rest of the job.

What technique the camera framework been used regarding to scaling and format translating.

Any Hardware acceleration tech involved?

--

I just learned that if the underlying was camera 1,
it use opengles to scale and render to multi surfaces.
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/legacy/RequestThreadManager.java

Or implemented by OEM's Camera HAL?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the ISP (image signal processor) that receives the raw camera data has several scaler units, which can crop and scale each frame to multiple different sizes.

So on Android, the generation of multiple outputs is handled by the camera HAL of the device, typically heavily leveraging the ISP scaling capability.  Most high-end devices run the image sensor at full resolution (in photo mode at least) and hardware downscale for preview or other outputs.

The legacy code you point to was for implementing the new camera2 API on top of the deprecated camera1 API, which required doing scaling in the Android framework, where the GPU was leveraged for this since there's no generic access to ISP scaling units outside the camera HAL.  That code isn't used for modern devices that have an up-to-date camera HAL.

Comment: So, if i feed 3 output surfaces into one request.  The ISP module can generate 3 different resolution outputs for the latest frame? I was thought that the ISP can only output one certain resolution of frame stream.

Comment: Mobile SoC ISPs have multiple scalers; otherwise it'd be very hard, for example, to display preview on screen while recording video.  Exactly how many outputs can be requested in parallel, and with what sizes, depends on the capabilities of the device. The Android camera API defines hardware levels that state the number and kind of parallel streams that can be requested: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)